# Rails App RAKE ROUTES does not return anything

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes, rake

I built a rails app that I had working locally.  In deploying it to my web host, I changed from sqlite to mysql2 and updated some other gems.  The app is up on the web host, but now it doesn't run locally.  I've tried locally to use mysql2 and sqlite.
If I start the rails server in development (sqlite3) or production (mysql2), I can run `rake db:drop` `rake db:create` `rake db:migrate`. They run fine and I can confirm this in database browser or workbench.

When I run rake routes it doesn't find any routes.

```
 RAKE ROUTES --Trace
** Invoke routes (first_time)
** Invoke environment (first_time)
** Execute environment
** Execute routes
```

The above is all that is returned and when I browse to the main page of my application I get the error:

```
Internal Server Error: undefined method `info' for nil:NilClass
```

What would cause Rake Routes to ignore or not find all the routes in routes.rb?

Below is my routes.rb file.

```
MyApp::Application.routes.draw do

get "users/new"

get "answers/new"

get "quizzes/new"

get "flashcards/new"

resources :posts do
resources :comments

 resources :users
 resources :flashcards  #, only: [:new, :create, :destroy]
 resources :sessions, only: [:new, :create, :destroy]
 resources :posts, only: [:new, :create, :destroy]

  #get "users/enter"

root :to => 'pages#home'
match '/', :to => 'pages#home'

match '/contact', :to => 'pages#contact'
match '/about', :to => 'pages#about'  

match '/ghostx', :to => 'users#ghostx'
match '/users/1', :to => 'users#ghostx'

match '/enter', :to => 'sessions#new'
match '/exit', :to => 'sessions#destroy'

match'/flashcards', to:  'flashcards#index'
match '/check', :to => 'flashcards#check'
match '/flash', :to => 'flashcards#pullcard'
match '/search', :to => 'flashcards#search'
end
```

Comment: Did it used to work? If so, can you find the change you made that broke it?

Comment: How about posting your `routes.rb` file?

Comment: yeah, please post your routes file. Others (people interested) can better help you that way.

Answer (score 1):

You are opening two blocks but only have one `end` statement. Where is this block

```
resources :posts do
```

supposed to close?